# How do I run prettier on a specific subdirectory on my project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, glob, prettier

I have a typescript project structure something like this:

```
--workflows
    |--app1
         |--src
    |--app2
         |--src
```

I am trying to run prettier, but I only want to run on app1.

I tried something like this:

```
prettier --write \"workflows/app1/**/*.{js, ts}\"
```

This doesn't return any files.

But if I run something like this:

```
prettier --write \"workflows/**/*.{js, ts}\"
```

It returns all files under workflows directory.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get it to run only for files under app1?

Comment: Try it without escaping quotes, i.e. `prettier --write "workflows/app1/**/*.{js, ts}"`. Escaping quotes actually includes them in the path.

Comment: @Steve I can't. I am writing it I package.json file. Something like this
"scripts": {
      "review": "prettier --write \"workflows/app1/**/*.{js, ts}\""
}

If if remove the escapes, it starts erroring out

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Since it's in JSON, it actually is running it without the escaped quotes. It looks to me like it should run correctly.

Comment: It worked without using quotes
prettier --write workflows/app1/**/*.{js, ts}

Answer (score 9):

It worked without using quotes

```
prettier --write workflows/app1/**/*.{js, ts}
```

Json looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "review": "prettier --write workflows/app1/**/*.{js,ts}"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs you can use a `.prettierignore` file in the root of your project: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Simply create a file called .prettierignore and type the directories you want to exclude in your case:

```
app2
```

You can also use the `--ignore-path` option in the CLI